Data type is not changing in MongoDB via databricks Pyspark ( from string to date)
I am trying to load multiple documents into the MongoDb collection using databricks pyspark and while loading I am using updateDate filed as well , but after loading I could see updateDate field data type is string instead date data type.
here i am using the code for timestamp.
import datetime

current_timestamp_utc = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
formatted_timestamp = current_timestamp_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
timezone_offset = current_timestamp_utc.strftime("%z")
formatted_timestamp = formatted_timestamp + ".000" + timezone_offset[:-2] + ":" + 
timezone_offset[-2:]

print(formatted_timestamp)

result : 2024-04-03T07:33:52.000+00:00

as per the result looks fine , but after loading into MongoDb , it is displaying as String instead Date.
So could you please help me on this how to load the documents with date data type.
I have used UpdateMany() method to change string to date data type and is this the write approach to proceed or is there any I/O or performance impact while using updatemany() method . Please suggest

You use strftime(), so why do you expect a Date as result, you compose a string. And why do you use + timezone_offset[:-2] + ":" +  timezone_offset[-2:] instead of simple strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")? The + ".000" is pointless either.

If you want to insert a Date value the simply try to insert datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) directly. A Date value itself does not have any format.

Thank you for providing the details, but I would like to store in this format 2024-04-03T07:33:52.000+00:00 in MongoDB as per the requirement and When I tried to use datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc), getting 2024-04-04 10:26:58.241295+00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>.

No again, a Date does not have any format (or at least it has a format you should not care about at all). What you mean is how the date is displayed at your client, but this has nothing to do how the value is stored internally in your database.

I don't know spark at all. Perhaps you cannot use it directly, then you would need to convert the Date into a string (apparently that's what you did) and then convert the string into a BSON-Date. Have a look at $dateFromString

You can get the current time directly using spark SQL date-time functions as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, current_timestamp

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.sql("""select date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.SSSxxx") as updateDate""").show(truncate=False)

Output:
+-----------------------------+
|updateDate                   |
+-----------------------------+
|2024-04-04T09:04:35.865+00:00|
+-----------------------------+

Schema:
root
 |-- updateDate: string (nullable = false)

If you notice the schema, updateDate is a string and you can convert it into a timestamp using to_timestamp() as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, current_timestamp, to_timestamp

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.sql("""select to_timestamp(date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.SSSxxx")) as updateDate""").show(truncate=False)

Output:
+-----------------------+
|updateDate             |
+-----------------------+
|2024-04-04 09:04:12.703|
+-----------------------+

Schema:
root
 |-- updateDate: timestamp (nullable = true)

And now the updateDate is a timestamp adjusted for your spark session's timezone (that's why the +00:00 offset is gone now) - which, by the way, you can update using spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "<enter-timezone-here>").
And if you want to add it to an existing dataframe as a new column you can do something like this:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, current_timestamp

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,)], ["rownum"]) # replace this with your dataframe

df = df.withColumn("updateDate", date_format(current_timestamp(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.SSSxxx").cast("timestamp"))

df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()

Output:
+------+-----------------------+
|rownum|updateDate             |
+------+-----------------------+
|1     |2024-04-04 09:04:48.473|
|2     |2024-04-04 09:04:48.473|
+------+-----------------------+

Schema:
root
 |-- rownum: long (nullable = true)
 |-- updateDate: timestamp (nullable = true)

The datatype you are looking for is a timestamp with a timezone in Spark. Now, you can try loading the dataset into MongoDB with this schema.

I have tried the below approach in Pyspark:
DataFrame.printSchema of DataFrame[id: int, date: string]
df1 = Dilip_df.withColumn("date", to_date("date", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))

Results:
+---+----------+
| id|      date|
+---+----------+
|  1|2022-01-01|
|  2|2022-01-02|
|  3|2022-01-03|
+---+----------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: date (nullable = true)

In the code above, I used the withColumn() function to create a new column called "date" and use the to_date() function to convert the "date" column to the DateType.
The format string "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" specifies the format of the input date string.
However, As you mentiond you are loading files to MangoDB
As per the $toDate (aggregation)
$toDate Converts a value to a date. If the value cannot be converted to a date,
$toDate errors. If the value is null or missing, $toDate returns null.
You can also try the below in the MangoDB in 4.2 version:
from datetime import datetime
mydate = datetime.strptime(‘08/12/1977 09:45:34 AM’, ‘%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p’)
mydate = mydate.isoformat()

Reference: String Datatype to Date datatype conversion
$convert (aggregation)
